# F# Recursion to Summarize a Path given by List of Points

Tags: list, recursion, f#

I am new to `F#` and have stumbled on a problem that I am interested in. I am trying to recreate similar functionality to `List.reduce` with recursion instead. The function uses `sumTwoPoints` to calculate the sum of two elements in a list of coordinates and returns one element.

```
let sumTwoPoints(x1, y1) (x2, y2) : float * float = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

What I have done so far:

```
let rec pathSum list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> failwith "Empty List"
    | head::next::rest -> sumTwoPoints head next :: rest
```

My thought process is this

```
// e0() e1() e2() e3() e4()...
// sumTwoPoints (e0 e1) = r1
// sumTwoPoints (r1 e2) = r2
// sumTwoPoints (r2 e3) = r3 
// sumTwoPoints (r3 e4) = r4
// pathSum = r4
```

The `e0` represents the element in the list. If we go by this system, `head = e0` and `tail = e1` and the `rest` list has leftover elements. I am not sure about adding the new `r1` to the `rest` list, but that is what I came up with. The next step, if my logic is correct, is to pass this new list to  `pathSum`, but get again, I don't know how to achieve that in the code.

My proposed solution might be completely wrong, and any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A follow up to what [Charles Mager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320845/charles-mager) as answered you need to look at list. It can either be empty `[]`or have the value of another list `x::y`. If you take a closer look at your functions

```
sumTwoPoints : (float * float) -> (float * float) -> (float * float)
pathSum : (float * float) list -> (float * float)
```

This way you have `rest` as the type of `(float * float) list` which when called with `pathSum` gives the type `(float * float)`. This way you can utilize the function `sumTwoPoints` without the need of `next`

```
 let rec pathSum list =
    match list with
    | [] -> (0.0, 0.0)
    | head::rest ->
        sumTwoPoints head (pathSum(rest))
```

And lastly you will need to change `failwith` to give zero as otherwise it will fail the recursion.

Comment: Think should be `sumTwoPoints head (pathSum(rest))` - otherwise, neat solution!

Comment: Correct, was just a typo. TOm marked the answer so hopefully he saw that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to modify your function to add a parameter for the current point.

The logic would be that it adds the 'head' of the list to that point, then recursively calls itself with the result of that addition and the rest of the list. When it's finally called with an empty list, it simply returns the point value.

```ml
let rec pathSum (current:float * float) list =
    match list with
    | [] -> current
    | head::rest ->
        let next = sumTwoPoints head current
        pathSum next rest
```

The initial call would have to pass an initial value of `(0, 0)`:

```ml
pathSum (0, 0) list
```